# About basicLTI java implementation (basiclti-util-java), ¿documentation?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, lti

I've as objective to create a simple "Hello World" as an LTI app. To do so, I would like to use JSP, so I look for a Java implementation of LTI to make it.

After looking for it, I found this github repository: https://github.com/IMSGlobal/basiclti-util-java

Where they've created some utils implementating LTI 1.0. The only problem about it, it's that I can't found any example nor documentation about how to use it.

The only way I think I can understand a bit about how to use it, is looking the Test classes they've created, but this only helps me in the methods way, and leaves me still without knowing how must I create the "app" (servlet? JSP? any special methods? What should be used first?

I'm a bit lost with all this. Can anyone give my a piece of advice or a way to start?

Thank you in advance

(PS: tried to tag it as LTI, but I've no reputation enough..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of that project, and I'm glad you're interested in LTI!

There are many different aspects of LTI, but the main thing people are referencing when they talk about LTI is the oauth launch. You can read more about that [here](https://www.edu-apps.org/code.html).

Here's a [sample java lti app](https://github.com/pfgray/lti-example-java)  I wrote with the spring framework which uses basiclti-util-java, which might get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering Paul! I'll check both links, while read a bit about spring then, because I've never used it. Thanks again!